# Firebase authentication failing in app download from playstore.

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have my app ready and it is published. As I have the release version of my app in before putting it on playstore then the phone authentication in firebase is working fine but as I post it on playstore and download it from there then it show me an error of authentication failed.

Comment: Make sure you have added the SHA-1 from the release keystore to the Firebase Console.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Yes I already have. The release version of app works fine before publishment but as I download it from the playstore it won't work. I need immediate help.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add sha1 from play store to firebase console .
play store sha1 will be provided when you upload the apk